# SELECT clause with count and condition more than 2

Tags: sql, oracle

For example.
having these two tables

```
//DEPARTMENT
DNAME
----------
RESEARCH
   IT
 SCIENCE
```

DEPTLOC table

```
//DEPTLOC
DNAME        CITY       STREET
--------------------------------
RESEARCH    BOSTON        41
   IT       LONDON        22
RESEARCH    NEWYORK       33
 SCIENCE    ENGLAND       22
```

So when i run this statement

```
SELECT DNAME FROM DEPARTMENT d 
    WHERE (SELECT count(CITY,STREET) from DEPTLOC having by > 2
//using having by
```

what should i write in order to get result like this
the DNAME will be show if location more than 1 mean 2 or above
One location is mean CITY+STREET

```
//OUTPUT
DNAME
-----------
RESEARCH     <-- displayed because got 2 location , more than 1
```

Comment: yes @michael. anything you dont understand ? sorry for my bad explanation

Comment: You've provided a sample data set and query, but it is not clear what your desired result is.

Comment: 1. does it need to match both city and street or if one of them is different will you count them as different locations? 2. if `DEPTLOC` has all the department names, why do you need the table `DEPARTMENT`?

Comment: @rhealitycheck - The `DEPARTMENT` table could be used as a constraint/lookup table when joined to `DEPTLOC`

Comment: Does the DEPTLOC table contain DNAME column? If not, with which column do you join the DEPARTMENT and DEPTLOC tables?

Comment: answered by  Linoff ! thanks

Comment: thanks but been answered by gordon. sorry for my bad explanation but somehow some of them still understand what i trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT dl.DNAME
FROM DEPTLOC dl
GROUP BY dl.DNAME
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: +1 : On the assumption that `DNAME, CITY, STREET` is unique.  *(And `FROM DEPTLOC`.)*

Comment: Your code fail to run as the location is at DEPTLOC and not at DEPARTMENT

Comment: @user3553846 - Come on, surely you can use your own initiative and make that change on your own?